# Methods for cross-sectional twin data (GEE, mixed effects modeling, GLMM)?

Tags: mixed-model, spss, multilevel-analysis, paired-data, generalized-estimating-equations

I have a twin dataset of 248 pairs (166 MZ, 82 DZ) that was gathered at one time point. I'm interested in looking at the relationship between a physiological biomarker and self-reported insomnia levels. The biomarker is continuous, but I want to break it into categorical cut-offs so it is easier to interpret (this is how it is commonly treated in the literature). Therefore, I have a categorical predictor and continuous outcome. I'd like to first examine this relationship, and then examine if this relationship is also affected by adding physical activity levels (self-reported, continuous) as another predictor. Next, I'll examine if season of measurement (categorical) moderates any significant relationships. I have a number of confounds that I want to adjust for (e.g., gender, BMI), as well.

I plan to model these relationships first cross-sectionally (accounting for correlated nature of data), and then separately for MZ and DZ twins to assess for genetic and familial confounding.

I'd like to analyze the data in SPSS, but have access to Stata and SAS if necessary. Both my biomarker and insomnia variables are non-normal (positively skewed), but do not fit the non-normal models that are typically analyzed using generalized linear mixed models. Therefore, I'd like to use GEE or linear mixed effects models with transformed variables. However, is there an approach that would be appropriate/better that I'm missing? Also, does anyone have an opinion on whether GEE or mixed effects modeling is more appropriate for these data?